# Facilitate transfer between Amazon FPS buyer and third party seller, how to return to store?

Tags: payment-gateway, amazon-fps

I would like to Facilitate transactions between a buyer and a third party seller on my fixed price market place. I will allow third party sellers to accept direct payement for their goods from the buyer using Amazon FPS.

Here is my questions... I would like the buyer to be taken back to my website after completing the payment. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

User is automatically redirected to your site when he clicks "Confirm Order" button, because payment transaction actually should be initiated on your side. On the Amazon page user just approve his intention to make transaction and special payment token is generated.